# How can I submit form content to a Rails app from a static page?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an existing static HTML page and I wish to add an email signup form. In the interest of time I don't want to re-create the page as a view. Is it possible to use a static form to submit new emails to a Rails controller?

On the HTML page:

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="emails">
<input type="text" class="inputbox">
<input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="button" />
</form>
```

existing Rails controller:

```
def create
  @subscription = Subscription.new(params[:subscription])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @subscription.save
      format.html { redirect_to @subscription, notice: 'Subscription was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @subscription, status: :created, location: @subscription }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @subscription.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `name` attribute on an input will determine the hash key in `params`.

So then

```
<input type="text" name="foo">
```

will be available through

```
params[:foo]
```

Comment: Works, thanks! I had to get around a stringify_error with @subscription = Subscription.new(:email => params[:subscription])

Answer (score 1):

Use `<input type="text" class="inputbox" name ="subscription[name]">` assuming that name is the field in your subscription table.